# fullcalendar - can't get basic display

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Stumbled at the first hurdle with FullCalendar.  Can't even get the basic display.  This is my code inside the `<head>` tags:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='fullcalendar.css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title  : 'event1',
            start  : '2010-01-01'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event2',
            start  : '2010-01-05',
            end    : '2010-01-07'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event3',
            start  : '2010-01-09 12:30:00',
            allDay : false // will make the time show
        }
    ]
});

});
</script>
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: are you receiving any javascript errors? Can you link to the site?

Answer (score 1):

it's hard to diagnose with so little info.... I'm also using full calendar. Make sure you have an element with id="calendar" on the page, check to see if any errors show up in Firebug (or your inspector of choice). You may try using more attributes in the event object (id may even be required).

If it's helpful, you can check out my implementation at http://www.cafekaribo.com/event.

if none of this helps, please post a link, errors, or an in-depth description of what actually happens.

**example database insertion**

```
$db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);
$query = 'INSERT INTO events (event_start) VALUES ('2014-01-01');
$res = $db->query($query);
```

Comment: Pizaul, Thanks for the response.

Comment: Sorry - don't know what happened there...  I've managed to get the basic display working.  I have scoured the web but cannot find an example of how to put an event INTO a MySQL database.  Plenty on populating FullCalendar FROM a database, but not inserting into a database.  Have you come across how to do this?  Any help appreciated.

Comment: that's just going to depend on your application. Full Calendar doesn't affect that at all, see my updated answer for an example of how one might add a date via php / mysql. Don't forget, if an example is helpful, vote it up. If an answer provides a solution, accept it!